# How can i handle findspark.init() index error?

Tags: python, apache-spark, bigdata, google-colaboratory

This is my code :

`!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://www-us.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.1/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar xf spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!pip install -q findspark`

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7"

import findspark
findspark.init()
```

I have searched but i couldn't find solution,I am using findspark.init() here and it gives this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-ea4df208c52b> in <module>()
      1 import findspark
----> 2 findspark.init("/content/")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    133     # add pyspark to sys.path
    134     spark_python = os.path.join(spark_home, 'python')
--> 135     py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, 'lib', 'py4j-*.zip'))[0]
    136     sys.path[:0] = [spark_python, py4j]
    137 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: it's missing py4j  so you have to install it.  **pip install py4j**

Comment: No, no not because of that. I have answered the solution.

Comment: "https://www-us.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.1/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz" isn't on the server, OP's code gives an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use actual versions. So the code will be like :

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://www-us.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.3/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar xf spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!pip install -q findspark

import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7"


import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thanks. I was getting the same error. This solution helped me resolve the error.